# Parsing mobileprovision files in bash?

Tags: iphone, bash, shell, plist, adhoc

I am tying building a php/bash/mysql system for automating adhoc distribution for iPhone apps. But I want to read the application-identifier key in mobileprovision file of projects and change it info.plist file according to that.

I can currently build ipa files from php IF the cfbundleidentifer key is same as its provision file.

I found a code like this https://gist.github.com/711794 but I want bash script to integrate it to my system.

Thanks

Comment: Asking a question usually help get an answer. What you want?

Comment: I've read much worse questions than this. I think @egray is asking how 'to read the application-identifier key in mobileprovision file of projects and change it info.plist file'. Cordially!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If your running this on a machine with mac os x, you can use the following:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :Entitlements:application-identifier' /dev/stdin <<< $(security cms -D -i path_to_mobileprovision)
```

Comment: Oh! thanks for the `security cms -D -i path_to_mobileprovision` tip! I was getting a lot of `Unexpected character 0 at line 1` errors before

Answer (score 29):

If you want to extract the plist from the mobileprovision in a proper way and not rely on grepping/sedding/etc., you can use OpenSSL as follow:

```
openssl smime -inform der -verify -noverify -in file.mobileprovision
```

A complete example in your case could be:

```
openssl smime -inform der -verify -noverify -in file.mobileprovision > tmp.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :Entitlements:application-identifier' tmp.plist
```

The OpenSSL part should work on any platform, although I've only done that on a Mac so far. PlistBuddy is only on Mac, but other utilities can be found to read/write property list files.

Answer (score 14):

I created a bash function based on jlawrie's answer to list all .mobileprovision's bundle IDs from the `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` folder.

Save this into your `.bash_profile` and just call it with `list_xcode_provisioning_profiles` from a terminal.

```
list_xcode_provisioning_profiles() {
    while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
        2> /dev/null /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :Entitlements:application-identifier' /dev/stdin \
            <<< $(security cms -D -i "$f")

    done < <(find "$HOME/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles" -name '*.mobileprovision' -print0)
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly.Thanks!

Comment: For those who don't know how to insert that on `.bash_profile`, `touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile`, copy and paste the source provided, save it, restart the terminal window and them just use `list_xcode_provisioning_profiles` like suggested.

Comment: default shell changed to zsh, so add it to `~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 6):

One solution among many...

Use egrep with the -a option, which treats binary files like text files and '-A 2' which will display the two lines after the string you want to match: ApplicationIdentifierPrefix.

After that,  trim the line of brackets and whitespace using sed.

Using a series of pipes:

```
egrep -a -A 2 ApplicationIdentifierPrefix file.mobileprovision | grep string | sed -e 's/<string>//' -e 's/<\/string>//' -e 's/ //'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is mildly tedious, since a .mobileprovision is "PKCS #7 signed data" or so.

Fortunately, you can probably get away with using grep :)

Answer (score 0):

I used the code from [mobileprovision-read](https://github.com/0xc010d/mobileprovision-read) repository to be able to pull information from the mobileprovision file.  This uses macOS APIs to read the file.

Here is the usage from running the generated program:

```
mobileprovision-read -- mobileprovision files querying tool.

USAGE
mobileprovision-read -f fileName [-o option]

OPTIONS
    type – prints mobileprovision profile type (debug, ad-hoc, enterprise, appstore)
    appid – prints application identifier
Will print raw provision's plist if option is not specified.
You can also use key path as an option.

EXAMPLES
mobileprovision-read -f test.mobileprovision -o type
    Prints profile type

mobileprovision-read -f test.mobileprovision -o UUID
    Prints profile UUID

mobileprovision-read -f test.mobileprovision -o ProvisionedDevices
    Prints provisioned devices UDIDs

mobileprovision-read -f test.mobileprovision -o Entitlements.get-task-allow
    Prints 0 if profile doesn't allow debugging 1 otherwise
```