# xcodebuild / Jenkins can't find the PROVISIONING_PROFILE for an iOS job

Tags: xcode4, jenkins, code-signing, xcodebuild

I can build with Jenkins/xcodebuild when the project has the correct Provisioning Profile selected.

We want to be able to set the provisioning profile in xcodebuild.

Unfortunately, when the jenkins user runs

`xcodebuild PROVISIONING_PROFILE="XXX"`

...*Lots of build output*...

> `Check dependencies`
>
> `Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'XXX' can't be found`

I can run the same line and have it work with a regular user account, accessing the file in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/

The provisioning profiles are stored in `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/LibraryMobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`

Anyone know where else the Jenkins user would be looking for these?

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to the provisioning profile, like so?:

`xcodebuild PROVISIONING_PROFILE="/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles"`

Comment: Tried and that does not work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question: the provisioning profiles **must** be named after the UUID.

If you download and do not rename a .mobileprovision file, it will not be read by `xcodebuild`

[A script for doing so is in another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11167851/389159)