# Script to copy and rename file fails on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, command-line-interface, provisioning-profile

I followed this question: [Provide xcodebuild with .mobileprovision file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128284/provide-xcodebuild-with-mobileprovision-file/11167851#11167851) and used the script provided in the answer to try and copy .mobileprovision files into the directory, the only difference is I replaced the mParse dependency using grep, as per a suggestion in this link: https://gist.github.com/benvium/2568707

However, when I run this script I get the following error:

```
$ sh installMobileProvisionFile.sh BuilderTestNew.mobileprovision 
Found UUID 402a766e-bfc7-4f16-8ab6-a46a95361b00
copying to ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/402a766e-bfc7-4f16-8ab6-a46a95361b00.mobileprovision..
cp: ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/402a766e-bfc7-4f16-8ab6-a46a95361b00.mobileprovision: No such file or directory
done
```

If I just run the cp command executed in the script by myself replacing the variables for the above values it works normally, so I can't understand why it fails when using this script? I am on Yosemite by the way.

EDIT:

Here's the adapted script:

```
if [ ! $# == 1 ]; then
 echo "Usage: $0 (path/to/mobileprovision)"
exit
fi

mp=$1

uuid=`grep UUID -A1 -a ${mp}| grep -io "[-A-Z0-9]\{36\}"`

echo "Found UUID $uuid"

output="~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/$uuid.mobileprovision"

echo "copying to $output.."
cp "${mp}" "$output"

echo "done"`
```

Comment: It looks like your cp is only passing a single argument. Am I crazy? It would definitely help to see your modified script.

Comment: Nope, the command line argument gets passed to the cp command normally, it seems to be a problem with the double quotes as they make the mobileprovision file a part of the path.

Comment: What do you see when you echo your source and target variables?

Comment: The output variable is there `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/402a766e-bfc7-4f16-8ab6-a46a95361b00.mobileprovision`, as for the source variable it prints the file name `BuilderTestNew.mobileprovision` as expected

Comment: Is your source provisioning profile in the same directory as your script? Sorry - going through the motions. ;)

Comment: Yes, it is placed in the same directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `cp` command in `Bash` you need to provide the full path of the files. Aliases such as `~/myFolder` won't work. You will need to provide a full path such as `/Users/Me/myFolder`.

Comment: This was a "duh" moment for me :/