# How to install a OSX .provisionprofile on a mac machine via Terminal / CLI?

Tags: macos, provisioning-profile

I want to write a script that installs some OSX .provisionprofile files on a macOS machine, but i cannot find any information online on how to install this type of provisioning profile via the Terminal.

Everywhere, people just mention and ask about iOS .mobileprovisioning which is a whole different thing and they're really easy to install with a script.

Is it possible to install a OSX .provisionprofile via CLI? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Seems OSX provisioning profiles are treated the exact same way mobileprovision profiles are for iOS. This means you can just copy them in "~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles" and rename them to their uuid.

Code example can be found in the answer here: [Can an Xcode .mobileprovision file be 'installed' from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398456/can-an-xcode-mobileprovision-file-be-installed-from-the-command-line/10775025#10775025)