# Add path for mobileprovision file in exportOptionsPlist option when exporting ipa file with xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, plist, xcodebuild

I am using following command to export an ipa-File from a created iOS application archive:

> xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath app.xarchive -exportOptionList
> ExportOptions.plist -exportPath build

In my `ExportOptions.plist` file I have an entry which specifies which mobileprovision file should be used:

```
<key>provisioningProfiles</key>
<dict>
 <key>my.company.app</key>
 <string>filename_for_provisioning_file</string>
</dict>
```

`filename_for_provisioning_file` is located in my home directory which seems to be a valid location where the file is searched by xcodebuild.

**Question**

Is there a possibility to add a specific path in `ExportOptions.plist` which points to `filename_for_provisioning_file` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no possibility "to add a specific path in `ExportOptions.plist` which points to `filename_for_provisioning_file`".

You **must** specify a provisioning profile that is **installed**.

**Installed** provisioning profiles are stored under **/Users/<YOUR_USER_NAME>/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/**

If you run `xcodebuild --help` on the terminal, you will see towards the end a section named "**Available keys for -exportOptionsPlist:**", that states

> provisioningProfiles : Dictionary

```
    For manual signing only. Specify the provisioning profile to use for each executable in your app. Keys in this dictionary are the bundle identifiers of executables; **values are the provisioning profile name or UUID to use.**
```

If, for any reason (such as continuous integration etc), you'd like to automate the process of 'installing' the provisioning profile, you could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10775025/4944020) and read the larger discussion under that question for more context and information.

Comment: Okay, I just noticed that I have already installed the provisioning profile with the crypted UUID name. So the file in my home path was not read at all. However, I simply copy the provisioning profile file to /Users/<YOUR_USER_NAME>/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/ and it is working now.
No need of magic or UUID creation. Just copy.

Comment: Glad to know you've got it working for you. Thank you for accepting the answer. All the best.