# How to get around Apple app ID insanity

Tags: xcode

As you all know, Apple changed how Xcode works such that you can't ever create an app with a previously used app ID, even if you're just writing test apps to use locally. Up until now I've just been typing in garbage IDs to get around this stupid antifeature, but today I was greeted with this gem:

[image: Unable to add App ID because the '10' App ID limit in '7' days has been exceeded.]

So now I'm blocked from creating any more test apps, effectively stopping my development dead in its tracks (I write libraries and frameworks, and need to test them in test apps).

Does anyone know of a way to bypass or disable Apple's restrictions?

Comment: Why not create a wildcard App ID in the developer portal?

Comment: @Karl I'm in the same predicament; have you found any official word that Apple is deliberately restricting development in this way? I create and tear down apps to try things and just got bitten by this this morning. If this is truly the case, that one has to resort to a workaround of creating new Apple IDs, then Apple is going to have its hands (orchard?) full of duplicate IDs very soon, creating a new problem for them. I don't see how this restriction benefits anyone, unless they think someone getting started learning iOS coding will be happy using the simulator alone and then pay to play.

Comment: @CharlesCavanaugh - Re: the "Looking for an answer from an Apple representative." in your bounty, this isn't really the right place for that. No one from Apple will see this here, nor do they make a habit of commenting on policy decisions in public Stack Overflow questions. If you want an official response, I recommend using the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: I haven't touched Xcode in over a week, and this just popped up, which really worries me. There's no way I deployed 10 new things if I haven't been on Xcode. What's going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Same thing happened to me. I presume it's some kind of a new limit that Apple has put on "non-paying" developers, and that it limits you to 10 apps in 7 days.

Edit - To resolve this, I'll just make a random apple dev ID...

Comment: I'd like to know if that is in fact the case, that it is a new limit purposely added by Apple, but I can't find anything straight from Apple about it. This is ridiculous. Limiting how many different apps I can test, that I write, on my own iPhone to 10 every 7 days? Learning how to code in iOS can be done using a simulator, but I find the restriction crazy, especially since I was using some sensors that the simulator doesn't simulate. Come on, Apple? Is this for real?

Comment: No, it's NOT A SOLUTION.

Comment: I'm even getting this issue in Xcode. I tried to create a new Bundle identifier and in the signing section, it gave me this error. It won't let me create new iOS apps on my Mac to test in the simulator either.

Comment: Another "workaround" is to use an id that you previously created. But that will not allow you to use other app anymore. then again it's not a solution but a workaround

Answer (score 33):

It is a kind of limit of free developer accounts, but you could figure out a solution for that:

1- Navigate to  the project of any previous application that have been installed on the same device has the problem with .

2- Open `Build Settings tab` for the app project in `Xcode` .

3- Search for `Bundle ID` and copy it .

4- Open up your current app that has the problem and navigate to the same place > Paste and Replace the current `Bundle ID` with the old one.

5- Run the app.

!!! WALA

Answer (score 11):

I faced the same situation in my new mackbook with xcode 7.3.1 version.
Even if I tried with ***old bundle identifier, it didnt worked.***
Following below steps helped me to run the app in device.

1. Got to xcode preference
2. Click accounts and choose your apple id.

[image]

3. Click the View details
   [image]
4. And Click download All.

This will download all the provisioning profile associated with given apple id.
And after that use any identifier that you have used before. You can easily get the old identifier from provisioning profile names.

Comment: this looks different in Xcode 9. no longer has View Details. just has Download Manual Profiles and View Certificates. anyone has tips for doing this in  xcode 9?

Comment: No longer works in Xcode 9. Wrote an answer here which lists all the bundle ID's you can reuse. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47763510/518169

Comment: @giovannipds are you facing this issue in xcode 9 ?

Comment: @Raj Hi! What issue specifically? The thread question or what mentioned on this answer? Not anymore, I get rid of this joining an organization where there's no app limit. =p

Comment: @giovannipds i mean the issue mentioned in the question. Because even if we use our personal account this issue wont happen anymore in xcode9.

Comment: @Raj I wouldn't be sure of that, I remember I'd experienced this on Xcode 9.

Answer (score 7):

Just use the bundle ID of any old app that you have already installed like this and change the bundle ID after 7 days. I think apple puts a limit for free developer accounts.

EDIT:
Its important about what @haquangvu mentioned in his answer that, your old app get replaced. So take care of it and thanks @haquangvu for your answer.

Comment: I suspect that, but what is the logic behind that? To get us to pay 99 bucks so we can distribute our not-ready-for-prime-time apps on their App Store? Before I start my annual subscription, I wanted to be able to learn and test my apps, on my iPhone (yea I could use the simulator but it is limited on the sensors), and gain a certain amount of proficiency, before I started the clock on my ability to distribute on the App Store--there's no sense in wasting the months when all I'm doing is testing on my own device. Why would Apple limit that?

Comment: @CharlesCavanaugh : yah you are right. No idea about what Apple intended about this.

Answer (score 5):

Use one of your old Bundle IDs. 
It works. 
But your old Application will be delete.

Answer (score 4):

> DO NOT MAKE ANOTHER ID thats not the solution!!!

To make it work thats what you need to do:

```
Window > Preferences - Account
```

Then choose your apple ID and your team, then click on `View Detail...` Button on the bottom right.

A new window will show up, click on `Download all` button on the bottom left and all of yours Provisioning Profile will show up.

After that just Left click on those ones you don't have to use anymore and click to move to trash.

after you delete enough profiles, you'll be able to build your project again!

Comment: didn't work ? even after closing and opening Xcode, http://i.imgur.com/Fn03Nap.jpg

Answer (score 3):

I had this and the other answers here didn't fix the problem. I solved it by opening Window > Devices, finding my device, right-clicking it to "Show Provisioning Profiles", and then deleting a bunch of the profiles there.

Then it worked!

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to use an id that you previously created. As Xcode does not list the Bundle IDs via Apple ID Details any more, save this into your `.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc` and call it with `list_xcode_provisioning_profile` from a terminal

```sh
list_xcode_provisioning_profiles() {
    while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
        2> /dev/null /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :Entitlements:application-identifier' /dev/stdin \
            <<< $(security cms -D -i "$f")

    done < <(find "$HOME/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles" -name '*.mobileprovision' -print0)
}
```

To make this answer easier to find I just copied it from hyperknot here: [Parsing mobileprovision files in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398364/parsing-mobileprovision-files-in-bash/47763510#47763510)

Answer (score 0):

I have a paid developer account and found this happening in Xcode 9 after creating a bunch of simple test/example apps. In the past, I would have simply selected a "wildcard" App ID. However, Xcode doesn't seem to have a way to do this anymore.

Researching based on the wildcard, I found [Technical Q&A QA1713: When should I use a wildcard App ID?](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1713/_index.html). Following these steps seems to have worked for me. (The signing errors are gone, but we'll see what happens in another 7 days or 10 apps, lol.)

Here are the steps, if you have a paid developer account:

1. Log into your developer account.
2. In the list on the left, click on *Certificates, Profiles & IDs*.
3. In the new list on the left, under *Identifiers*, click on *App IDs*.
4. Click the '+' symbol in the upper right of the page. (You're now at the 'Registering an App ID' page.)
5. In the box under *App ID Description*, enter something to describe your App ID. (Note that this description has to be purely alphanumeric; spaces seem to be allowed, but nothing else.)
6. Under *App ID Suffix*, select the radio button for *Wildcard App ID*.
7. In the box below that, enter the beginning of what you'd like to use as  your app's bundle identifier, followed by a dot-asterisk. (For example, maybe your app bundle identifiers in Xcode are something like `com.myname.appname`. Then, in the box under *Wildcard App ID*, you'd enter `com.myname.*`.)
8. Under *App Services*, select any available items you think you might use in an app at some point in the near future. (Only a few of the items are available for selecting at this step.)
9. At the bottom of the page, click the *Continue* button.
10. At the resulting 'Confirm your App ID.' page, scan your selections to ensure they're okay; then, at the bottom of the page, click the *Register* button.
11. At the resulting 'Registration complete.' page, you can again review the registered options. Then, just scroll to the bottom, and click the *Done* button.

The new wildcard App ID will now appear in your list of App IDs.

Next, go into Xcode, and create your app, **entering an Organization Identifier that matches the wildcard App ID** you registered *without the dot-asterisk*. (For example, if you enter `com.myname`, Xcode completes what becomes the bundle identifier with a dot and the app name.)

When the project opens at the signing page, Xcode will "Automagically manage signing" correctly ;)

***Note:*** If you have a free developer account, as of the date of this posting, you can't access the 'Certificates, Profiles & IDs' link in your account. ;(

Answer (score 0):

Me too I had the "limits you to 10 apps in 7 days" message, and was the wrong apple bundle name, so I copied the "test" bundle name, under the test `TARGETS` and paste it without the "RunnerTests" at the end, so:
com.<bundle_name>.myProject.RunnerTests ==> com.<bundle_name>.myProject

Answer (score -1):

1. Xcode>General>Identity
2. Copy Previous Bundle ID

   > Bundle Identifier : AppleDeveloperName-PreviousProjectName(or whatever)
3. Paste it in the new project's Bundle ID. It should be fine now.