# Unable to add App ID because the '10' App ID limit in '7' days has been exceeded

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting this weird error when I try to hit this button to fix this error for the app I just made. I am trying to run the app on my connected iPhone when I get this error:
[image]

When I hit `Fix Issue` I then get this error:
[image]

What does this mean, and how can I start testing apps on my phone again?

Comment: I just got the same error. As a temporary fix, to get things running on my iPhone, I went to General > Team > and changed it to none.

Comment: You are not alone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922738/how-to-get-around-apple-app-id-insanity

Comment: @rmaddy did just happen today or something? such a bizarre change

Comment: What is going on? I am receiving the same error...

Comment: My guess is that Apple created this limit to interfere with people who are creating entire ecosystems of sideloaded apps.

Comment: @funroll That may be true. I'd like to hear it from Apple, because I think that  this could backfire. There might be half-baked apps submitted to the App Store because the developer paid to remove this crazy restriction, and now she can submit to the App Store as well, so she might before she's ready. Also, there might be more phony Apple IDs created to circumvent this issue. Some might reconsider their plans to jump into iOS app development. This new stumbling block is not encouraging.

Answer (score 18):

Easiest workaround I've found: find a bundle id that you already used.

Just create new projects with whatever name you want, and then change the bundle id to be the same in each project.

This works fine if you don't actually need to have multiple apps side by side on your phone, but you need to create lots of apps to test different scenarios.

Comment: I noticed that your solution does indeed work. It warns me, though, that it might be expiring "soon" (doesn't say when). I hate that ambiguity. Also I like to start with a clean project each time. I've been a professional in computer science for 16 years, and I don't need Apple telling me how I should learn something new, or rushing me into starting my paid account, which up till now I thought would only be required to distribute apps on the store. Limiting what I do with my own phone on my own computer is overstepping.

Comment: @CharlesCavanaugh True, atleast now I can use my apple id to sign apps, earlier even this was not possible. But I bumped into this issue today, and I dont even have an option to delete App ID on developer portal. Bummer !

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what are the ID's I've already used. Wrote an answer for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47763510/518169

Comment: How to get the bundle ID without code. I just have IPA of files is there any way to change from IPA file alone?

Answer (score 0):

For me this trick worked: just use another provision profile of any app that you have on your account.