# Xcode 9 stoped signing way before weekly limit

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, code-signing-certificate

I am a beginner Swift/Xcode user, and during one of my build/runs I got an alert saying:

> **App installation failed**
>
> The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached.

I only have 3 projects, each only has one product except for one that has 3 (iOS, tvOS, and macOS). I have built/ran each of them a few times before I got the alert. I know that there is a limit on how many apps you can sign per week, but I thought it was like 10 and not 6. I tried to build/run the other projects and all of them gave me the same alert.

I am on macOS 10.13.4 Beta (17E170c) with Xcode 9.3 beta 4 (9Q127n), my iOS device is on iOS 11.3 (15E5178f)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get around Apple app ID insanity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922738/how-to-get-around-apple-app-id-insanity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that works for you, because I have both a free profile and an apple dev-account, but it works for me on my free profile:

When you don't need more than 3 projects at your iPhone at a time you can uninstall an app (project), just like normal apps. That way you should be able to run / install another project to your phone.

Comment: That worked, I deleted one of the apps that I didn’t need and I was able to build and run the other two apps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just try with other Apple ID, it works.
That limit counts, if you're installing an app to new device too, and, maybe, you have used Cydia Impactor, it will counts too. So you can just use other Apple ID

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate limits. There’s a limit of 10 registered App IDs per week and a separate limit of how many personal team apps can be installed on your device simultaneously. The advice above to remove one from your device is accurate.