# how to read application's certificate information in IOS

Tags: ios, certificate

I have developed an SDK which can help application to sell it's in-app equipment. Because the SDK has billing feature, when my SDK be loaded by application, I need to ensure this application is authenticated, so I need to read the application's certificate information to verify it. I can find those API in android platform easy just like below:

```
pis = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
Signature[] sigs = pis.signatures;
```

but I can not find same API in iOS. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The app bundle has a `embedded.mobileprovision` file which contains data including certificate and provisioning profile used to sign the app. You can parse the data to obtain the info you want

```
NSString* bundleDirectory = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString* db = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/embedded.mobileprovision", bundleDirectory];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:db];
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: @ChrisZhao any luck ?

Comment: Yes, I have get embedded.mobileprovision file's data and in memory watch windows I even saw some certificate information, but I can not parse this file through IOS API, I am just research how to parse this file...

Comment: @ChrisZhao found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398364/parsing-mobileprovision-files-in-bash

Comment: Yes, Vincent, After following your suggestion, Now I can parse embedded.provision file and get the developer certificate data. Unfortunately, It is seemed IOS open API was not provide enough interface to parse a X509 certificate but only can get a summary string about this certificate. I am not sure what the summary means exactly, It seemed the combined string of developer name and team string?

Comment: Anyway, I don't want to involve openssl in my project because my image has too large, and I think the summary string has give me enough information to verify developer. So I think I can say I have resulved this issue. Thank you very much for your kindly help.